# Reverse integer digits

Tags: ruby

I was trying to reverse the digits of an integer: `123456 => 654321`, and the best solution that I could come up with was `123456.to_s.reverse.to_i`. I feel that this is too much of code. Anyone have a better approach than this?

Comment: I don't think you can improve on that. It's an unusual transformation to need. It also only makes sense once you have chosen a string form of the integer. Note you lose ending `0`s (as they become leading zeros in the reversed form, and for integers that is a property of how they are displayed, not inherent to the data).

Comment: You find 18 letters as too much code for this not so trivial task? :)

Comment: Not a shorter one, but faster:  
`def reverse(n)
  r = 0;
  r, n = (r*10 + n % 10), n / 10 while n != 0;
  r
end`

Comment: @NeilSlater u just helped me to prevent a big production issue , that could have happened due to loss of ending `0's` :)

Comment: @SašaŠijak i am just being greedy ,as with every question asked i am suggested a new better approach in the past :)

Comment: @eugen can you prove it?

Comment: @darek-nedza see https://gist.github.com/eneagoe/7890670 The difference is probably not very significant, but it does grow with n.

Comment: Indeed, it grows with n. As I played with your code, I think, it depends on when number start being Bignum.

Comment: The task you're doing is a pretty nonsensical task. That is, there's no reason you should be doing this in real life, rather than just as a computing exercise. Therefore, it's not surprising it takes three steps to do it.

Comment: Your initial solution is fine.

Answer (score 7):

This is a very "code golf"-ish answer, and not something I'd suggest writing in real code...

But you can shave an extra character off the answer with:

```
123456.to_s.reverse.to_i
123456.digits.join.to_i
```

Or (again, only as a 'code golf' answer!!) if you're happy to end up with a `String` rather than an `Integer`, you can make this even sorter with:

```
123456.digits*''  #=> "654321"
```

In fact, converting to a string might actually be *preferable*, because it may prevent loosing information from missing zeros. Code-golf answers aside, compare:

```
43210.to_s.reverse #=> "01234"
43210.to_s.reverse.to_i #=> 1234
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is another way without converting string....

```
x = 12345
y = 0

while x > 0 do
    y = y*10
    y = y + (x%10)
    x = x/10 

  puts y      
end
```

This algorithm can be asked in many interviews as well....not matter which language you use....this logic will be same.
above example using Ruby

Answer (score 1):

We can achieve this in an object level like the following.

```
class Integer
  def reverse
    number = self
    reversed = 0
    reversed, number = (reversed*10 + number % 10), number / 10 until number == 0
    reversed
  end
end

p 1234.reverse => 4321
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there're only two ways to achieve that in general:

1.

```
n = whatever
result = 0
while n > 0
  d, m = n.divmod(10)
  result = result * 10 + m
  n = d
end
```

2. Convert to str, reverse, convert back (you did this).

Computer memory is binary so it has no idea of decimal (I hope this is the right word) digits so you need to "introduce" them.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a fast one-liner for various online competitions for positive integers:

```
number = 123456778
p 0.then { |ch|  (number./(10).tap { |x| ch, number = ch * 10 + (number - x  * 10), x } while (number > 0)) || ch }
```

But this is unreadable. To make it readable:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby -w

number = 123

ch = 0

while (number > 0)
    div = number / 10
    mod = number - div  * 10

    ch = ch * 10 + mod
    number = div
end

p ch
```

Dealing with negative integers:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby -w

number = -123

ch = 0

negative = number < 0
number *= -1 if negative

while (number > 0)
    div = number / 10
    mod = number - div  * 10

    ch = ch * 10 + mod
    number = div
end

ch *= -1 if negative

p ch
```

Using `Kernel#then()` and `Kernel#tap()` will also enable you to write this in one line, the ugliest way.

Answer (score 0):

Compare 2 solutions.

```rb
# @param {Integer} x
# @return {Integer}
def reverse1(x)
  x.to_s.reverse.to_i
end

# @param {Integer} x
# @return {Integer}
def reverse2(x)
  rev = 0
  while x != 0
    pop = x.remainder(10)
    x /= 10
    rev = rev * 10 + pop
  end

  rev
end

# ********************#
#     Benchmark       #
# ********************#

require "benchmark"

x = 12320238
Benchmark.bm do |bm|
  bm.report("reverse1: ") { reverse1(x) }
  bm.report("reverse2: ") { reverse2(x) }
end

# user     system      total        real
# reverse:   0.000010   0.000003   0.000013 (  0.000009)
# reverse1:   0.000017   0.000005   0.000022 (  0.000021)
```

Answer (score -1):

## Reverse digits of an integer in Javascript

#### Solution

```
var reverse = function(x) {
  let result = 0
  while (x) {
    result = result * 10 + x % 10
    x = x / 10 | 0
  }
  return Math.abs(result) > 2147483647 ? 0 : result
};
```

#### Input Example

```
console.log(reverse(-1254))
```

#### Output

```
-4521
```